# wp_redirect() Error in Custom Plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-redirect

I wrote this script to handle theme switching about four years ago.  Since upgrading to WordPress 4.8, it is no longer working and is returning this error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_redirect() in /mnt/stor1-wc1-dfw1/388438/795069/www.flagstaffarizona.org/web/content/wp-content/plugins/custom-theme-switcher/custom-theme-switcher.php on line 50**

Anyone have any ideas of what might be causing this?  I've tried disabling all plugins except for this one, and it is still occuring.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Theme Switcher
Description: Handles Mobile Theme Switching
Version: 1.0.1
*/

add_filter( 'template', 'custom_theme_redirect' );
add_filter( 'option_template', 'custom_theme_redirect' );
add_filter( 'option_stylesheet', 'custom_theme_redirect' );

function custom_get_subdomain() {
$subdomain = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    $host_tokens = explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    if (!empty($host_tokens)) {
        return strval($host_tokens[0]);
    }   
}
return $subdomain;
}


function custom_theme_redirect($theme) {
if (!is_admin()) {
    if (isset($_GET['mobile'])) {
        setcookie("mobile", true, time()+1, '/', CUSTOM_ROOT_DOMAIN);
        setcookie("nomobile", false, time()-1, '/', CUSTOM_ROOT_DOMAIN);
        $_COOKIE['mobile'] = true;
        $_COOKIE['nomobile'] = false;
    }
    if (DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE == CUSTOM_MOBILE_DOMAIN || isset($_COOKIE['mobile'])) {
        if (isset($_GET['nomobile'])) {
            setcookie("mobile", false, time()-1, '/', CUSTOM_ROOT_DOMAIN);
            setcookie("nomobile", true, time()+1, '/', CUSTOM_ROOT_DOMAIN);
            wp_redirect('http://'.CUSTOM_MASTER_DOMAIN.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;
        }
        $theme = 'custom-mobile';
    } else if (DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE == CUSTOM_MASTER_DOMAIN) {
        include_once("Mobile_Detect.php");
        $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
        if (CUSTOM_AUTO_MOBILE_REDIRECT && $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()) {

            if (!isset($_COOKIE['nomobile']) || !$_COOKIE['nomobile']) {
                wp_redirect('http://'.CUSTOM_MOBILE_DOMAIN.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

}
return $theme;
}
```

Comment: It could be an error in your script causing this issue, try to change `$detect = new Mobile_Detect;`  to `$detect = new Mobile_Detect();`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I tried this and it still gives the same exact error as mentioned above.

Comment: Can you try to use wp_safe_redirect() function, Gist Url, https://gist.github.com/debabratakarfa/ba8f24bab1f69e99f46ab0122a2f0d97
Thanks